# How to properly implement the Action Listener in a bullseye animation

Tags: java, animation, javafx, javafx-8, actionlistener

This program first displays a bullseye created by three different sized circles.
Once the animate me button is clicked, the function `animation()` will make the existing circles shrink inwards until the size of the circles is zero.

Once the user presses the button named "Press to stop", the animation will then stop. If the user presses the button again, it will then keep going from the state it was stopped from, so on so forth.

Currently, this is not working as intended. It only creates about 9 circles (including the nine circles that the program began with). I know I will need to use the action listener in order to make the program run, but I'm having a hard time in terms of the documentation of the action listener. What am I supposed to put in the parameters of the listener? If you see any other ways around this, please feel free to let me know.

```
package target;

import javafx.animation.ScaleTransition;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Target extends Application 
{
    Circle[] cir = new Circle[7];
    Button btn = new Button("Animate me!");
    StackPane root = new StackPane();

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    /** 
     * start method will create the target and the start button first 
     * displayed on-screen to the user 
     */
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) 
    {

        root.setStyle("-fx-border-color:black;");      

        cir[0] = new Circle(400, 250, 200);
        cir[0].setFill(Color.RED);
        cir[0].setStyle("-fx-border-color:black;");

        cir[1] = new Circle(315, 165, 115);
        cir[1].setFill(Color.WHITE);
        cir[1].setStyle("-fx-border-color:black;");

        cir[2] = new Circle(230, 80, 30);
        cir[2].setFill(Color.RED);
        cir[2].setStyle("-fx-border-color:black;");

        root.getChildren().addAll(cir[0], cir[1], cir[2]);      
        root.getChildren().add(btn);     

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();

        btn.setOnAction(e ->
        {
            animation();
            btn.setText("Press to Stop");
        });
    }

    public void animation()
    {
        //Timeline animation = new Timeline(
        //)

        ScaleTransition[] st = new ScaleTransition[7];
        boolean recycleCircles = false;

        st[0]= new ScaleTransition(Duration.seconds(7), cir[0]);
        st[0].setToX(0.0f);
        st[0].setToY(0.0f);
        st[0].play();

        st[1] = new ScaleTransition(Duration.seconds(5.5), cir[1]);
        st[1].setToX(0.0f);
        st[1].setToY(0.0f);
        st[1].play();

        st[2] = new ScaleTransition(Duration.seconds(4), cir[2]);
        st[2].setToX(0.0f);
        st[2].setToY(0.0f);
        st[2].play();

       // int delayInc = 1;
        int delay = 1;

        //will create circles (will rotate between white and red) and then add 
        //to scaleTransitions
        //while(btn.isPressed() == false)
        {     
            for(int i = 3; i<st.length; i++)
            {     
                if(recycleCircles == true)
                {
                    i = 0;
                    recycleCircles = false;
                }
                if(i % 2 == 1)
                {
                    cir[i] = new Circle(400,250,200);
                    cir[i].setFill(Color.WHITE);
                    cir[i].setStyle("-fx-border-color:black;");
                    root.getChildren().add(cir[i]);
                    cir[i].toBack();

                    st[i] = new ScaleTransition(Duration.seconds(7), cir[i]);
                    st[i].setDelay(Duration.seconds(delay));
                    delay++;
                    st[i].setToX(0.0f);
                    st[i].setToY(0.0f);
                    st[i].play();

                }
                else if(i%2==0)
                {
                    cir[i] = new Circle(400, 250, 200);
                    cir[i].setFill(Color.RED);
                    cir[i].setStyle("-fx-border-color:black;");
                    root.getChildren().add(cir[i]);
                    cir[i].toBack();

                    st[i] = new ScaleTransition(Duration.seconds(7), cir[i]);
                    st[i].setDelay(Duration.seconds(delay));
                    delay++;
                    st[i].setToX(0.0f);
                    st[i].setToY(0.0f);
                    st[i].play();
                }
                if(i == 6)
                    recycleCircles = true;
            }
        }

        //btn.pressedProperty().addListener(listener);

        btn.setOnMousePressed(event ->
        {   
        });   

        btn.setOnMouseReleased(event -> 
        {
            for(int y = 0; y<st.length;y++)
            {       
            }
        });


    }  
}
```

Comment: If one of the answers solved your problem please mark one as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether you have any specific use case with each circle. If your are using the circles only for the purpose of alternating row colors, then you can get similar effect with radial gradient's repeat option.

To the extent I understand the question, below program is what I can think of. May be this can help you.

Just to let you know, the overall effect is slightly different from your program. The main difference in effects is, your program gives an effect/impression that each circle are shrinking towards center, as the distance between each circle is always same till it shrinked completely.
My program gives the effect/.impression like the entire board is moving away from your sight till it vanishes. In my program the distance between each circle decreases proportianally till it shrinks.

```
import javafx.animation.ScaleTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class TargetAnimation extends Application {
    Button btn = new Button("Animate me!");
    StackPane root = new StackPane();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        root.setPrefSize(400, 400);
        root.setStyle("-fx-border-color:black;");

        Circle board = new Circle();
        board.setRadius(200);
        board.setStyle("-fx-fill:radial-gradient(focus-angle 0deg , focus-distance 0% , center 50% 50% , radius 21% , repeat, red 44% , white 46% );-fx-stroke-width:1px;-fx-stroke:black;");

        root.getChildren().addAll(board, btn);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();

        ScaleTransition transition = new ScaleTransition(Duration.seconds(7), board);
        transition.setToX(0);
        transition.setToY(0);
        btn.setOnAction(e -> {
            switch (transition.getStatus()) {
                case RUNNING:
                    transition.pause();
                    break;
                case PAUSED:
                    transition.play();
                    break;
                default:
                    board.setScaleX(1);
                    board.setScaleY(1);
                    transition.playFromStart();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code given to `setOnAction` is an [`EventHandler`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.base/javafx/event/EventHandler.html), which is a `@FunctionalInterface` with the single method `handle`. That means that you can give it a lambda expression instead. The method takes an argument, which is the `ActionEvent` of clicking the button (created for you by JavaFX), and runs the code you give it.

If you want to pause the animation, call [`Animation#pause`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/Animation.html#pause()), and if you want to resume it, call [`Animation#play`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/Animation.html#play()). I suggest that you create a [`ParallelTransition`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/ParallelTransition.html) with all of your `ScaleTransition`s as its children. Then call the above methods on the `ParallelTransition` in the event handler.

That means that the setup code, like naming the button and creates the animations, goes *outside* of the event handler.